# Disjoint Cycle Question

Tags: permutations

I'm working on this question:

> List the permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ in disjoint cycle form.

I already know what a disjoint cycle is. It's basically means that every cycle contains numbers that are not in any other cycle. So with that in mind, do I write all the possible permutations of

\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
? & ? & ?
\end{pmatrix}

such that I could write down all of it's permutations in disjoint cycle form? A push to get me started is all I'm asking for here.

**EDIT**
Please see finalized answer below.

Comment: I know that I can arrange the $2nd$ row $3!$ (or $6$) ways.

Comment: If the bottom row is $3\ 2\ 1$, can you write the resulting permutation using cycle notation?

Comment: $(1 3)(2)$ correct?

Comment: Right! And so you've found one of the six permutations, written in disjoint cycle form. (It's common also to just write $(1\ 3)$, ignoring cycles with a single element, but neither is "the right way")

Comment: Ahh so once I collect all of them, I will have some repeats. So $(1 3) = (3  1)$ correct? And that will count as $1$ instead of $2$ permutations.

Comment: Yeah, representations for disjoint cycles aren't unique, $(1\ 3) = (3\ 1)$, or even $(1\ 2)(3\ 4\ 5) = (4\ 5\ 3)(2\ 1)$. So for each of the $3!$ ways to arrange the bottom row, you'll have some freedom in *how* you write the permutation in cycle notation (just choose one), but distinct permutations have legitimately distinct cycle notations.

Comment: Ahh alright. In that case, I will post a full solution and we'll see if it comes our correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempted:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1  \end{pmatrix} is given by $(1 3)(2)$.
Then \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\3 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}is given by $(1 3 2)$.
Then \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 2& 3 & 1\end{pmatrix} is given by $(1 2 3)$.
Then \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\2 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} is given by $(1 2)(3)$.
Then \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\1 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} is given by $(1)(2 3)$.

Lastly, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} is given by $(1)(2)(3)$, but these are just the identity matrices, so we can eliminate $(2)$ and $(3)$ and are only left with $(1)$.

So therefore, the final list of permutations is given by $$(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132).$$

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, but I used my phone to type all this up. Can someone perhaps edit this for me?

Comment: The cycles you found are good, the list at the end is just a bit funny

Comment: Hmmm funny how? Was my notation weird in any way?

Comment: Hmm how about now?

Comment: You have seven permutations listed; the first three, $(1),\, (2)$ and $(3)$ are all notations for the identity permutation (although you'll only ever see $(1)$, not the others, in practice). So get rid of $(2)$ and $(3)$ (or write $(1)(2)(3)$, no commas), then you're just missing one permutation: $(1\ 2\ 3)$.

Comment: Ah alright I will edit my answer.

Comment: +1 for learning quickly and answering your own question. Once you know cycle notation you will never want to write the two line form.

Comment: Yes I have that in mind Ethan. And thanks.