# Isomorphism and Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm am working on this question:

> Find a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_4$ that is isomorphic to $S_3$.

**What I know (thus far):**

Motivated from one of my [past questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209610/disjoint-cycle-question), I have that $$S_3 = \{(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$$ 
Thus, I can chose (with some relabeling) $$H_a = \{(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$$

as a subgroup of $S_4$. *If* this is correct, why so?

Comment: I think it would help to clarify your notation: since $S_3$ acts on three elements and $S_4$ on four elements, you could write $H = \{(1)(2)(3)(4),(12)(3)(4), \ldots, (132)(4)\}$. Then show an isomorphism between $H$ and $S_3 = \{(1)(2)(3), (12)(3), \ldots, (132)\}$.

Comment: Ah yes. I will edit my question later this afternoon when time permits.

Comment: To show the isomorphism, try sending a permutation $\sigma \in S_3$ to $\sigma(4) \in H$.

Comment: Ah so as long as $4$ is fixed, I can send any permutation $\sigma$ from $S_3$ and it would be in $S_4$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course, $4$ is arbitrary; you could fix any other element of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to end up with a different subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: I see. Well that clears my doubts then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The idea behind that is the following.

The group $S_4$ is the group of permutations of $4$ objects, let's call them $\{1,2,3,4\}$. The subgroup you defined simply is the subgroup of $S_4$ given by permutations that don't move $4$. It should be obvious why it is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: Well as you said,we leave $4$ fixed. Since I'm fairly new to the concept of isomorphsms, how would I show that there is an isomorphism between $H$ and $S_3$, using Théophile's remarks? I don't see how this is obvious. I $do$ know that there must be a bijection of some sort and that the group operations are preserved.

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 Just define a map $S_3\to S_4$ by sending $\sigma\in S_3$ to the element of $S_4$ keeping $4$ fixed and acting as $\sigma$ on $\{1,2,3\}$, and show that it is an injective group homomorphism.

Comment: That's what I had in mind and Théophile cleared it up as well.